# Какие веб технологии используются при разработке интерактивных сайтов с использованием drag-n-drop

Tags: drag-n-drop

Какие технологии, решения, языки используются при разработке интерактивных сайтов с использованием функции drag-n-drop? Например, mindmap, построение инфографики, или, вообще figma и т.д. Как правило, речь идет об веб-приложениях. Хотелось углубиться в эту тему, поучиться, посмотреть видео, почитать. Может поможете добрым советом. Спасибо.

Comment: эммм...джаваскрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На чистом JS: https://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-drag-and-drop.

Библиотеки: https://www.cssscript.com/best-drag-drop-javascript-libraries.

А вообще глупо что-то спрашивать, если есть поисковые системы.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Андрей лучше примите ответ галочкой рядом с ним.